# Star and Numbers logic puzzle

Tags: mathematics, pattern

This was on the entrance exam at our local university last year.
I still can't figure out the answer...
[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> 61

Because

> Each number on the point is the sum of the squares of the numbers connecting to it.

Comment: Any intuition about whether there's a pattern to the inner numbers?

Comment: I doubt it. If anything, it seems to be made to be easy to figure out. Putting 5 or 6 next to 4 would give 41 or 52, neither of which is obviously a sum of squares. Although four of them being multiples of five might be an intentional red herring.

Comment: @ParthianShot: (n+1) goes to n-th unfilled field clockwise

Answer (score 11):

> $5^2 + 6^2 = 25+36$= **$61$**
>
>  Its just square and add

Comment: The way I saw it was noticing that the bigger numbers in the "outer circle" seem to relate to the bigger number in the inner circle. Then I first noticed $5^2 + 1 = 26$, and seeing $4, 3$ and $25$ we have the famous pythagorean triple giving $4^2 + 3^2 = 5^2$

Comment: @Improve same case with me...coz I also saw the famous pythagorean triplet first...and later came to the conclusion.. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Every number at the points is equal to the sum of the squares of the closest two numbers inside, so it's 25+36=61.